# Bootstrap dropdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I try much but can't solve this drop-down menu problem. How bootstrap doc say I do here same and check stackoverflow ago question answer but it no work in my file. I upload my file in `dropbox` to check it u can see [here](https://db.tt/455sKT1O) also 
and my code given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

    <title>Hey! Whats up?</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    -->

 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>


                        </ul>



                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try this one: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729308/sub-menu-is-not-showing-up/33729395#33729395](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729308/sub-menu-is-not-showing-up/33729395#33729395) I hope This Should Work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jquery before bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `jquery`. According to [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included):

> jQuery required
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

```
<head>
    <title>Hey! Whats up?</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your drop down function is intialized.